# Calculate sum check

Tags: serial, rs232

I'm trying to send some serial commands.

In the manual of the hardware it says:

Sum check byte is the summation of all bytes. Higher order bytes are ignored and and the final result is modified. Bit 7 (highest) is forced high.

Let's say the serial command is: (where 0x30 = 30)

30 30 70 7E 61 62 63 7E 30

... what would be the checksum and how can I calculate it?

What are "higher order bytes"? What is a "modified" final result? What does "is forced high" mean?

Answer (score 3):

You should include a link or picture of the manual page or so to be sure.

I could hazard a guess, though, and you could see if it works for you.

Start with an empty 8 bit variable.

For each byte in the command, add the byte to the variable.

Since the sum may end up being larger than 8 bit, the 'correct' sum would include a 'high byte' also. However, using an 8-bit variable will cause the sum to rollover. You can also use a 16-bit variable and mask it with 0x00FF or a 32 bit variable and mask it with 0x000000FF. In most cases, apply the mask after adding all the bytes.

Finally, force the highest bit (bit 7) to 1.

For your example, the checksum should be calculated as:

30 + 30 + 70 + 7E + 61 + 62 + 63 + 7E + 30 = 322

Strip out the high byte :

22

Force the MSB to 1:

A2

Comment: Thank you so far, what does MSB mean?

Comment: @Darwin Most Significant Bit.

Comment: And how can I determine this MSB?

Comment: Use a HEX to binary* convertor, 22 in binary is 00100010, when padded with zeros to make it 8 bits. Replace the left most bit (the MSB) with 1, and reverse.

Comment: 22 is 0001 0110 isn't it?

Comment: 22 is not twenty two. It is 22 in HEX. 22(base16), or 34(base10).

Also, when I say reverse, I mean invert the process. Convert the binary back to hex.

Comment: As you have a 8 bit checksum, You can do it by chksum = chksum | 0x80;

Comment: Okay, so let's do this: 30+30+70+2F=FF FF is 11111111, MSB (1st bit) is already 1, so no change. So the check sum would be FF, wouldn't it?

Comment: What would happen If I had > 8 bits after the summation? Should I just cut them? 0011 1011 0100 would then be 1011 0100, MSB is already 1, so the check sum would be B4?

Comment: @Darwin : Yes. You are correct.

Comment: So if it says the _7th_ bit is the _highest_ I assume they are using an 7-bit checksum? The question now is: Is the _hightest_ bit the most left or the most right one?

Comment: bit 7 is the 8th bit, generally. It's a zero based list of bits, ie bits in decreasing order of significance are 7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0.

Comment: They talk about the checksum being in the range of 20 to 7E. This would mean B4 is out of range? Could it be that they strip these bytes and do: 0011 1011 0100 => 011 0100 => 111 0100 => 0x74?

Comment: It could be. Link to manual or images of manual pages.